# Ask labor supply under cobb-douglas preferences

Tags: microeconomics

Suppose an individual has an endowment of T units of time that she can devote to labor
supply (L) or leisure (R), so T = L + R. There is one consumption good in the economy,
denoted C, of which she has no endowment. Her endowment bundle is thus $(\omega_R, \omega_C ) = (T, 0)$.
Let the price of the consumption good be one, and the wage $w$.

(a) Show that if the individual has Cobb-Douglas preferences over leisure and consumption bundles, then her labor supply is independent of the wage (i.e., her choice of R and L does not depend
on $w$).

(b) Now suppose that her Cobb-Douglas preferences are described by the utility function
$u(R, C) = R × C$
and that her wage is initially $w = 1$. If the wage increases to $w = 2$, decompose the change in
her labor supply into the income effect and the substitution effect.

(c) Use your calculations in (b) to explain your answer to part (a).

My attempt:

For part a, I can write down the utility function, say $u(C,R)=alnC +b ln R$

I need to $\max alnC +b ln R $ such that $C + w R = wT$. I can plug in $C = wT-wR$. Then I take the first order condition, set it to be 0. Then I find $R=\frac{b}{a+b} T$. I find there is no $w$ in the function. So I solve out a?

I don't know how to do part b.